# что за ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, filter

функция принимает массив строк и возвращает только те, которые содержат не менее 5 гласных (a, e, i, o, u).

```
function filter5Vowels(obj) {
    let array = obj.map(vowels5 => {
        const regex = /[aeiouAEIOU]/g
        const resRegex = new RegExp(regex)
        let str = vowels5.match(resRegex)
        if (str.length >= 5) {
            return vowels5
        }
        return null
    })
    let arr = []
    arr = array.filter(function (s) {
        return s !== null
    })
    return arr
}
```

Comment: match вернул null (если ничего не было сопоставлено)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) возвращает `null`, в случае, если не было найдено ни одного совпадения.

Для решения можно либо добавить соответствующую проверку, либо воспользоваться [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) оператором.

---

Также стоит обратить внимание, что первый `map` можно заменить на `filter`, и сразу получать итоговую коллекцию:

```
function filter5Vowels(obj) {
    return obj.filter(vowels5 => {
        const regex = /[aeiouAEIOU]/g;
        const resRegex = new RegExp(regex);
        let str = vowels5.match(resRegex);
        return (str?.length >= 5);
    })
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но все равно не получается)

Comment: @user458911, что именно не получается? Метод работает именно так как и ожидается.

Comment: эта задача тест прошла. Но почему то когда я пытаюсь проверить эту функцию таким образом console.log(filter5Vowels(['bhjhkd', 'aoietba', 'aioaouaoai'])) то выходит ошибка которую я выше написала

Comment: @user458911, в версии из ответа такой ошибки быть не может. Скорее все проверялась какая-то другая версия функции.